# Var_dump поместить в переменную

Tags: php

Как можно поместить в переменную `var_dump();` что бы вывести тогда, когда это нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы сохранить дамп переменной в строку, можно использовать функцию [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

Пример:

```
$test = [2,4,[5,6]];
$dump = var_export($test, true);
echo $dump;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, это работает как я и хотел.

Answer (score 3):

Можно взять информацию из буфера вывода.

```
ob_start();
var_dump($var);
$dump = ob_get_clean();
```

См. также:

1. Описание [функций контроля вывода](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php)

Comment: Я тоже так делаю. Такой вывод более информативен, чем var_export